# Saving model instance with DateTimeField in Django Admin loses microsecond resolution

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-orm

In Django 1.8, let us say we have this very simple model:

```
class Log(models.Model):
    remarks = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

When I save a model instance to my PostgreSQL database, the `timestamp` field will have microseconds. I noticed that if I attempt to edit a particular model instance from the Django admin, the `timestamp` field will lose microsecond resolution when saved back into the database.

Most application would not need that level of accuracy, but for applications that do require such, it would be nice to be able to eliminate all possible causes of this loss of resolution. Is there any known way/feature to prevent this or is this a bug/limitation?

Comment: which db you are using?

Comment: @Alasdair - yeah, that was a typo from my end. my bad and thanks!
@svfat - PostgreSQL. I am also aware that MySQL does not support microsecond resolution, but the matter of the fact here is that the `timestamp` field loses the microsecond resolution when you update the model instance from the Django Admin.

Comment: As an aside, Django 1.8 and MySQL 5.6.4+ do support microseconds ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#database-backends))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the default admin widget does not support microseconds. You can override the widget with [`formfield_overrides`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) to use [`DateTimeInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#datetimeinput) instead, and specify a format that includes microseconds.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from django import forms

from .models import Log

class LogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    formfield_overrides = {
        models.DateTimeField: {'widget': forms.DateTimeInput(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')},
    }

admin.site.register(Log, LogAdmin)
```

In your case, since it's a timestamp, another option is to add the add the field to [`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields), so that it can't be changed at all.

Comment: It would have been nice to be able to retain the original widget and at the same time preserve microsecond resolution. As for the `readonly_fields`, other peculiar use cases might still require the ability to edit when needed. Anyway, thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: You could try digging into the code for the admin's date time widget, but I don't know how easy it would be to customise to include microseconds.

Comment: Tried this approach but I got the "Enter a list of values." validation error. Probably it is looking for the date and also the time value.